# Why is "Start Debugging" so much slower than "attach to process" in VC2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a program that holds sveral MB (up to GB) in hash tables (boost::unordered_map / unordered_set) etc. When is use "Start Debugging" in VC2010, freeing such a table may take incredibly long (several minutes), so i usually have to terminate the process. If i start the same binary without debugging freeing is done in a fraction of a second.
In both cases i use the same optimized release x64 build.

I read the 2 existing Questions to the topic:

- [What is the difference between Start Debugging and Attach to Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564026/what-is-the-difference-between-start-debugging-and-attach-to-process) and
- [What's the advantage for 'attach to process' compared with 'Start Debugging'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856075/whats-the-advantage-for-attach-to-process-compared-with-start-debugging?rq=1)

but they dont answer my question:
What specifically is done more when i start debugging, and is there a way to turn this off? What i need is detection of access violations and the possibility to set breakpoints etc. Being unable to pass through deallocations etc. sometimes is a real problem. Using "Start without Debugging" and later attaching to the process is not really making things easier.

Comment: My guess is that if VS has control over the launch it might have the possibility to track memory allocations and deallocations, maybe it does not do this anymore if the debugger is just attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start it normally then your program will be running with the Windows debug heap enabled.  Which is nice, it adds lots of pointer checking that will automatically invoke a break when the heap is about to be corrupted or you release a bad pointer.  But adds overhead that indeed can slow down your code when you debug with huge datasets.

The pragmatic solution is avoid debugging with jiggabyte datasets.  Or you can set an environment variable that disables the debugging heap.  Project + Properties, Debugging, Environment, add `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1`

Comment: Somehow i knew that you'll come up with the right answer. Thanks Hans!